# Can you sniff network traffic through a VPN tunnel?

Tags: vpn, tunnel, monitoring

**Background**:
I am doing research for building an automated penetration testing application. All tests will be run from some server with a public IP ("testing server"). The objective is to test specified hosts in some company's internal network, i.e., the network is shielded from the internet by some firewall. Access to the internal network is provided using VPN, the testing server connects as client to some VPN server on or through the firewall, thereby joining the internal network. It is planned to use protocols that tunnel layer 2 traffic, namely OpenVPN (TAP mode) or L2TP/IPSec. Besides directly sending packets to the target hosts, it would be very nice to be able to sniff normal traffic on the internal network, to analyze it for security flaws etc.

**Question**:
Provided that the server's NIC can be put in promiscuous mode, would sniffing the internal network through the VPN tunnel work? Which problems may arise? How could one achieve this? I imagine an issue could be the VPN server not forwarding traffic that is not addressed to the testing server (to safe bandwidth, or for privacy reasons).

**Bonus question**:
If any other possible issues with pentesting through a VPN tunnel come to your mind, please share them with me.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sniffing network requires you to either

- insert a sniffer into the network connection to be sniffed
- mirror traffic from switch/router ports to a sniffer

Since it's not really practical to run *all* traffic (to be analyzed) through a VPN connection, you'll need to mirror the traffic. However, since the VPN tunnel likely relies on the WAN connection for transport, that WAN link what need to have a rather large bandwidth, which isn't really practical either.

Technically, forwarding mirrored traffic via VPN should be a problem with the appropriate configuration.

Imho, the only practical way is to introduce a testing agent into the network and sniff/test using that. Of course, you could connect that agent via VPN to your own network for control.